Required Lookup field | Screen flow
I have a field in a screen flow. This field is used by different departments, but one in particular is asking me to make the field mandatory when the user navigates through the screen flow. The issue is that I'm trying different alternatives: from a formula in the same flow to make it mandatory only in that case, to a validation rule that checks if the field is not empty and also checks by record type (so the rule only acts when creating a task corresponding to that area). The problem is that I can't resolve it, because even though the rule works, it does so even when I put a value in the field. That is, I fill the field and the 'field is mandatory' error still appears. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Additional information (I think it's important): the field is a lookup field. I understand that this makes it a bit more complicated and that the origin of the problem might be there. If anyone can help me, I appreciate it. Best regards.

You cannot validate on whether a lookup field is blank in a ScreenFlow (it's a pain).
However, for a lookup, you can set the "Required" option to "{!$GlobalConstant.True}"
See for the more information: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_lookup.htm&type=5
